# The first argument to the plotly.graph_objs.layout.Template constructor must be a dict or an instance of plotly.graph_objs.layout.Template

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to plot this data frame as a line graph between `number_of_episods` and `mean_reward` using Plotly.

the data frame looks like this

```
,number_of_episodes,mean_reward,gamma
20000,20000,-40540.541935483874,0.85
20001,20001,-40540.541935483874,0.8499924999999999
20002,20002,-40540.541935483874,0.849985
20003,20003,-40540.541935483874,0.8499775
20004,20004,-40540.541935483874,0.84997
20005,20005,-40540.541935483874,0.8499625
20006,20006,-40540.541935483874,0.849955
20007,20007,-40540.541935483874,0.8499475
20008,20008,-40540.541935483874,0.84994
20009,20009,-40540.541935483874,0.8499325
20010,20010,-40540.541935483874,0.849925
20011,20011,-40540.541935483874,0.8499175
20012,20012,-40540.541935483874,0.8499099999999999
20013,20013,-40540.541935483874,0.8499025
20014,20014,-40540.541935483874,0.849895
20015,20015,-40540.541935483874,0.8498875
20016,20016,-40540.541935483874,0.84988
20017,20017,-40540.541935483874,0.8498725
20018,20018,-40540.541935483874,0.849865
20019,20019,-40540.541935483874,0.8498574999999999
20020,20020,-40455.302250803856,0.84985
20021,20021,-40455.302250803856,0.8498425000000001
20022,20022,-40455.302250803856,0.849835
20023,20023,-40455.302250803856,0.8498275
20024,20024,-40455.302250803856,0.84982
20025,20025,-40455.302250803856,0.8498125
20026,20026,-40455.302250803856,0.849805
20027,20027,-40455.302250803856,0.8497975
20028,20028,-40455.302250803856,0.84979
20029,20029,-40455.302250803856,0.8497825
20030,20030,-40455.302250803856,0.849775
20031,20031,-40455.302250803856,0.8497675
20032,20032,-40312.8782051282,0.84976
20033,20033,-40312.8782051282,0.8497525
20034,20034,-40312.8782051282,0.849745
20035,20035,-40312.8782051282,0.8497375
20036,20036,-40312.8782051282,0.84973
20037,20037,-40312.8782051282,0.8497224999999999
20038,20038,-40312.8782051282,0.849715
20039,20039,-40312.8782051282,0.8497075000000001
20040,20040,-40312.8782051282,0.8497
20041,20041,-40312.8782051282,0.8496925
20042,20042,-40312.8782051282,0.849685
20043,20043,-40312.8782051282,0.8496775
20044,20044,-40312.8782051282,0.84967
20045,20045,-40312.8782051282,0.8496625
20046,20046,-40312.8782051282,0.849655
20047,20047,-40312.8782051282,0.8496475
20048,20048,-40312.8782051282,0.84964
20049,20049,-40312.8782051282,0.8496325
20050,20050,-40312.8782051282,0.849625
20051,20051,-40312.8782051282,0.8496175
20052,20052,-40312.8782051282,0.84961
20053,20053,-40312.8782051282,0.8496025
20054,20054,-40312.8782051282,0.849595
20055,20055,-40312.8782051282,0.8495874999999999
20056,20056,-40312.8782051282,0.84958
20057,20057,-40312.8782051282,0.8495725000000001
20058,20058,-40312.8782051282,0.849565
20059,20059,-40312.8782051282,0.8495575
20060,20060,-40312.8782051282,0.84955
20061,20061,-40312.8782051282,0.8495425
20062,20062,-40312.8782051282,0.8495349999999999
20063,20063,-40312.8782051282,0.8495275
20064,20064,-40312.8782051282,0.84952
20065,20065,-40312.8782051282,0.8495125
20066,20066,-40312.8782051282,0.849505
20067,20067,-40312.8782051282,0.8494975
20068,20068,-40312.8782051282,0.84949
20069,20069,-40312.8782051282,0.8494825
20070,20070,-40312.8782051282,0.849475
20071,20071,-40257.645367412144,0.8494675
20072,20072,-40257.645367412144,0.84946
20073,20073,-40257.645367412144,0.8494524999999999
20074,20074,-40257.645367412144,0.849445
20075,20075,-40257.645367412144,0.8494375
20076,20076,-40257.645367412144,0.84943
20077,20077,-40257.645367412144,0.8494225
20078,20078,-40257.645367412144,0.849415
20079,20079,-40257.645367412144,0.8494075
20080,20080,-40257.645367412144,0.8493999999999999
20081,20081,-40257.645367412144,0.8493925
20082,20082,-40113.5923566879,0.8493850000000001
20083,20083,-40113.5923566879,0.8493775
20084,20084,-40113.5923566879,0.84937
20085,20085,-40113.5923566879,0.8493625
20086,20086,-40113.5923566879,0.849355
20087,20087,-40113.5923566879,0.8493475
20088,20088,-40113.5923566879,0.84934
20089,20089,-40113.5923566879,0.8493325
20090,20090,-39967.241269841266,0.849325
20091,20091,-39967.241269841266,0.8493175
20092,20092,-39967.241269841266,0.84931
20093,20093,-39967.241269841266,0.8493025
20094,20094,-39967.241269841266,0.849295
20095,20095,-39812.32278481012,0.8492875
20096,20096,-39812.32278481012,0.84928
20097,20097,-39812.32278481012,0.8492725
20098,20098,-39812.32278481012,0.8492649999999999
20099,20099,-39812.32278481012,0.8492575
```

now when I use this command

```
!pip install plotly==4.14.3
import plotly
import plotly.express as px
fig=px.line(df2,x='number_of_episodes',y='mean_reward')
fig.show()
```

it gives me this error

```
ValueError: The first argument to the plotly.graph_objs.layout.Template 
constructor must be a dict or 
an instance of plotly.graph_objs.layout.Template
```

I don't know what the problem is. I checked everything it seems fine, but I don't know what the problem
small note I'm using google Colab

Comment: it just works for me in my jupyterlab env with plotly 4.14.3 already installed.  I suggest moving `!pip install ...` into a separate cell and check `plotly.__version__` after it's run

Comment: I already did it and also on the Jupylab works but on Colab didn't work, and both of them in a separate cell

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the exectution environment and run again the cell as %pip install --upgrade plotly.